# iText7 pdfHTML c# doesn't respect baseuri on linux/unix systems

Tags: .net-core, itext, itext7

Hi currently i am evaluating IText7 and i finding really amazing but i came up to a bug i believe. Using latest version `pdfHTML 2.1.1 in .net core 2.2` setting the baseUri in order to access locally css and images works fine in windows but not on linux/mac.

```
private byte[] PdfGenerator(string html)
    {
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        var basepath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory,"asset");
        _logger.LogDebug($"Base path is :" +basepath);
        converterProperties.SetBaseUri(basepath);
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, memStream, converterProperties);
            return memStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Although in my running directory the `asset` folder exists with files underneath (css,images)
I get 2 different results for windows and mac

I link css in my html like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

**Windows**

[image]

**Mac**

[image]

The value of `basepath` is

**Mac** `/Users/gpapadak/Code/In.Backend/src/In.Report.Api/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/asset`
**Windows** `I:\_github\In.Backend\src\In.Report.Api\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\asset`

**Linux** `/repositories/publish/asset`

Any help or workaround?

Comment: There may be 2 issues here. File path separators and whitespace characters in paths. Please debug your code to verify.

Comment: What exactly is the value of your `basepath` on Windows, on Linux, and on Mac?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Happy new year!!! Any news on this?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and stumbled upon this unanswered question.

So for anyone who is struggling with this, the problem is due to the fact we are setting the baseUri with a PATH.

So in order to solve this, something like this has worked for me :

```
var basepath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory,"asset");
var uri = new Uri(basePath);
converterProperties.SetBaseUri(uri.AbsoluteUri);
```